# Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic, flag overused

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, flagging

This flag for closing questions is overused:

"Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. "

People are asking about actual financial products (bonds, exotic options, currency pairs) and somebody conflates this with that flag which deters endorsing a company.

Similarly, the edit feature is basically avoided when a very very slight rewording can get around the supposed prohibition.

This is a problem.

Comment: My $0.02 on the financial products: If the OP already has a specific product mentioned in their question for the purpose of asking about it to understand it better (e.g. how it is structured), then I think that's fine. The issue with specific securities arises either when (a) the OP asks if they should buy/hold/sell the specific thing, or (b) when the OP asks for suggestions about other specific things they should buy/hold/sell.